# Describe union of set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let S describe the set $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ where

$A_n = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y-x^{2n} \geq 0 \}$

I understand that S describes the set of points "inside of the parabola y = $x^2$, but am not sure how to prove this. Any ideas?

Comment: prove $a\in A_n \Rightarrow a\in A_1$ for positive integer $n$

Comment: @Isura Manchanayake, but doesn't that only work for n = 1?

Comment: no. Draw the graph and see.

Comment: Okay, thx . . .

Comment: Wait. We both have done a mistake. $S$ is actually $A_1\cup\{(x,y)|x\in(-1,1),y\in(0,1)\}$

Comment: for each $x$ consider the intersection with the vertical line at $x$. For $|x|>1$ these intersections get smaller for bigger $n$, but the opposite holds for $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean inside of the parabola $y=x^2$ is $\{(x,y):y\geq x^2\}$, it can be shown like the following.

Let $(x,y)\in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$

$\Rightarrow \exists n_0: (x,y)\in A_{n_0}$

$ \Rightarrow \exists n_0: (x,y)\in \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y-x^{2n_0} \geq 0 \}$

$\Rightarrow \exists n_0: (x,y)\in \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y \geq  x^{2n_0}\}\subset \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y \geq  x^{2}\}$ ....   ($n_0\geq1$)
$\Rightarrow (x,y)\in\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y \geq  x^{2}\}$

Let $(x,y)\in\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y \geq  x^{2}\}$

$\Rightarrow  (x,y)\in A_1\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$

$ \Rightarrow  (x,y)\in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$

So we have $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y \geq  x^{2}\}$